# include kind of property in html

Tags: android, html, xml, modularity

I have created a lot of UI working on Android platform.
There, I used xml. What happens in android is that
when you have a fairly large UI screen with multiple blocks/sections
putting up all the code inside one xml file could be messy.

So they have provided  tag.
What it does is :
We can create separate xml files defining separate components
and these separate xml files can be included inside one parent
xml.
This keeps the code very modular, easy to maintain and easy to debug.

Very recently I started working on HTML for some Web App,
and there is huge/huge UI on one single page.
i.e. multiple tabs and multiple sections in them.
Now, I don't want to put in everything inside one single html file.

Is there way by which I can create separate files and display them
one at a time or as per required.

Comment: You can use the html `<template>` tag ([html5rocks explanation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)). But you will probably want to use a server side template language like jade, liquid or handlebars. What server language are you using?

Comment: @LcLk we are using java

Comment: Some more info will be needed. What framework? Any HTML templating language? Are you using raw html files? Is there a front end JS framework like Angular, Ember, backbone, Flux?

Comment: Spring framework, raw html files. No front end JS framework

Comment: I haven't used Spring myself, but Spring MVC + Velocity gives you some nice templating options (ie. splitting html into modular components). See this blog post: http://vozis.blogspot.in/2012/07/spring-mvc-and-velocity-webapp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get Angular.js and then user ng-route together with a custom directive. It's pretty simple actually.

[Download their stuff.](https://angularjs.org/) And then call it on your HTML.
Also, add this script aswell: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js`

Should be pretty easy and you might learn something new.

Here, let me give you a hand. Create a file called `app.js`, add the following inside:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])

app.directive("nameOfElement", function () {

return {

    templateUrl:'badassPartial.html'
  };
});
```

On your HTML put this: `<html ng-app="myapp">`

Then create the file `badassPartial.html` this will be the partial.

And all you gotta do now is call it like so wherever you want to call it in your HTML: `<name-of-element></name-of-element>`

Note, the `<name-of-element></name-of-element>` is the name that you declare in `app.directive("nameOfElement", function () {` but for every camelCase you add a '-'
Hope this does something for you.

Also, you will need to create a new `directive` for every partial and then call their element.